# In bootstrap how to add borders to rows without adding up?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, border

I'm using bootstrap version 3.0.1 to make a grid and when I add a border to the rows of the grid I can see that the rows that are together add up there borders, I get a thicker border.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }

      .container {
        width: 420px;
      }

      div.row {
        border: 1px solid;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row heading">
        <div class="col-md-12">Header</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row subheading">
        <div class="col-md-12">Some text</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row footer">
        <div class="col-md-12">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is what [I get](http://jsfiddle.net/7cb3Y/) .
How can I use the border without the adjoining rows adding up their borders?, ie: I want all rows with a border of 1px.

Thank you

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can remove the border from  top if the element is sibling of the row .
Add this to css :

```
.row + .row {
   border-top:0;
}
```

Here is the link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7cb3Y/3/

Comment: <3 this! Do something like my implementation for a nice bootstrap matching line between rows - CSS: `.row + .row { padding-top:10px; border-top:1px solid #e5e5e5; }`

Answer (score 17):

Here is one solution:

```
div.row { 
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
.container div.row:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

I'm not 100% its the most effiecent, but it works :D

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronmallen/7cb3Y/2/

Comment: While I appreciate receiving credit for this answer I do believe Siddharth Sharma's answer is more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the border class from bootstrap:

```
<div class="row border border-dark">
...
</div>
```

For more details visit the following link: [Borders](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/)

Answer (score 3):

On my projects i give all rows the class "borders" which I want it to display more like a table with even borders. Giving each child element a border on the bottom and right and the first element of each row a left border will make all of your boxes have an even border:

First give all of the rows children a border on the right and bottom

```
.borders div{
    border-right:1px solid #999;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}
```

Next give the first child of each or a left border

```
.borders div:first-child{
    border-left:
    1px solid #999;
}
```

Last make sure to clear the borders for their child elements

```
.borders div > div{
    border:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row borders">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">Email</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-4">my@email.com</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">Phone</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-4">555-123-4567</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add the 1px border to just the sides and bottom of each row.  the first value is the top border, the second is the right border, the third is the bottom border, and the fourth is the left border.

```
div.row {
  border: 0px 1px 1px 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: That would leave the top div w/o a top border.

Comment: It would be nice to specify color.